# Ingress uses invalid namespace while trying to expose internal service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to expose kubernetes-dashboard via ingress nginx addon for educational purposes. Here is my `kubernetes-dashboard-ingress.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  rules:
    - host: dashboard.lc
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: kubernetes-dashboard
                port:
                  number: 80
            pathType: Prefix
            path: /
```

And kuberenetes-dashboard pod/service:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
dashboard-metrics-scraper-5c6664855-fksqb   1/1     Running   0          16m
kubernetes-dashboard-55c4cbbc7c-6v6jt       1/1     Running   0          16m
```

kubernetes-dashboard service blueprint:

```
$ kubectl get service kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile","k8s-app":"kubernetes-dashboard","kubernetes.io/minikube-addons":"dashboard"},"name":"kubernetes-dashboard","namespace":"kubernetes-dashboard"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":80,"targetPort":9090}],"selector":{"k8s-app":"kubernetes-dashboard"}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-08T08:50:51Z"
  labels:
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
    kubernetes.io/minikube-addons: dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  resourceVersion: "30326"
  uid: a4a9d00e-88ba-4ad3-9027-42a34f7e9e68
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.101.22.189
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.101.22.189
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

```
$ kubectl get services -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.107.4.195    <none>        8000/TCP   14m
kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.101.22.189   <none>        80/TCP     14m
```

I applied ingress configuration without any issues:

```
$ kubectl get ingress -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                CLASS   HOSTS          ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
dashboard-ingress   nginx   dashboard.lc   192.168.49.2   80      93m
```

But curl to 192.168.49.2 returns 503 nginx error. So, I went to nginx logs `kubectl logs ingress-nginx-controller-77669ff58-fprp4 -n ingress-nginx` and saw something wierd:

```
controller.go:948] Error creating upstream "default-kubernetes-dashboard-80": no object matching key "default/kubernetes-dashboard" in local store

controller.go:954] Error obtaining Service "default/kubernetes-dashboard": no object matching key "default/kubernetes-dashboard" in local store
```

It does look like Ingress trying to find service `kubernetes-dashboard` in namespace `default`, but it's actually in namespace `kubernates-dashboard` as specified in my Ingress yaml config and `-n` argument. My possible guess that `default` word in `default/kubernetes-dashbord` may specify not namespace but something else but I have not idea what to do about it.

Best Regards!

Comment: The service `kubernetes-dashboard` and the underlying pod should also be in the namespace `kubernetes-dashboard`

Comment: And they are! I updated my question, added information about services and pods in namespace `kubernetes-dashboard`

Comment: Noticed that the `kubernetes-dashboard` service is only exposed on 443 port, add the 80 as you are routing to the service on 80 port in the Ingress resource.

Comment: you are right! The problem was I tried to use production-like kubernetes-dashboard config from repo instead of just activating minkube addon. I fixed it. Updated my question with actual states of pods and services in `kubernates-dashboard` namespace. Dashboard service now using 80 port, but nginx still returns 503 with same log `no object matching key "default/kubernetes-dashboard" in local store`

Comment: Can you share yaml of the `kubernetes-dashboard` service.

Comment: since you do not specify an ingress class in your ingress manifest but your ingress shows that is has an ingress class, the default here may refer to the class. You dont show how you setup the controller, so hard to tell.

Comment: @ArifUlusoy I use minikube and just activated it's addon: `minkube addons enable dashboard`. Anyway, added output of `kubectl get service kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard -o yaml` to my question.

Comment: @TheFool I use minikube and just activated minikube ingress addon: `minkube addons enable ingress` and did not any additional setup actions for ingress-nginx controller

Comment: 1. try `curl` to the service `kubernetes-dashboard` within the cluster 2. verify the `endpoints` in the service 3. Verify that the pod is on 9090 port, since the targetPort: 9090 is added to the Service .

Comment: Maybe this error log belongs to another ingress from `default` namesepace which using `kubernetes-dashboard` service. Can you check other ingresses with `kubectl get ingress -n default` and their yaml.